# phpBB server doesnt have rights to write to cach files and store (fedora)

Tags: linux, php, fedora, phpbb, phpbb3

i am trying to make a project ive been working on called SnowBall and im using phpBB to do that but on step 2 the requirements and at the end it says

```
cache/:
Found, Unwritable
files/:
Found, Unwritable
store/:
Found, Unwritable
```

things i have tried:

⚫chmod 777

⚫chmod 002

⚫chmod 775

⚫chmod 660

⚫chmod 770

---

none of those worked any ideas help is appreciated thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would check is if SELinux is causing this issue. You may be able to do this by temporarily disabling it, or by looking at /var/log/audit.log.

If thats not the case, you need to establish where the files are being written to - It may well be that its where you expect, but as the errors are showing relative addressing the problem could be elsewhere.  (I don't use PHPBB, but I guess if you look for "Found, Unwritable" in the PHP code, you can hack a line near it to show the full path, maybe with something like echo $dirname($path variable).   Alternatively there may be a config file you need to set which has the base directory for the path.

Also, as you have "chmod" access, try chown those directories to the web user  (normally http, httpd or www-data - you can look which one by looking at who is running the web server or the usernames in /etc/passwd.   I don't think running chmod 777 is a great idea although it will allow files to be written regardless of owner - while  running chmod 002 is clearly wrong, allowing no one to read files, and only non-owner and non-group users to write files )

You should also check that all the parent paths are readable by the web user, and make sure the directories you are looking for exist.

Comment: i dissabled SELinux and now it reads "Writable" on all of them but is SELinux important???

Comment: SElinux adds a significant layer of security over and above regular Linux. I can't tell you if its important to you or not, but I can say that Ubuntu does not have it on by default - while in environments where security is a concern it is typically on. Not having it on will not cause software to break, but potentially will make hacking easier. If you are the kind of person who uses chmod in production, its not for you. If you are the kind of person who thinks SSH as root is an unacceptable risk, you want it. SELinux dies have targeted and permissive modes you may want to look at.

Comment: Ehh those thing don't scare me and ssh root is good for me so it's fine then for me